# Swift - Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Since upgrading to Xcode7, I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSDictionary' with an argument list of type '(objects: [AnyObject!], forKeys: [String])'
```

on this line of code:

```
self.sessionBids!.addObject(NSDictionary(objects: [PFUser.currentUser().objectId, PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("username"), self.bidTextField.text], forKeys: ["user", "name", "bid"]))
```

Can someone explain why?

**EDIT: Here is the full block of code**

```
if(self.bidTextField.text!.rangeOfString("^[0-9]*$", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil) {
                    self.sessionBids = array[0].objectForKey("bids") as? NSMutableArray
                    var lastSessionBid : NSDictionary
                    SVProgressHUD.showProgress(50)
                    var previousHighBid : Int! = 0
                    if(self.sessionBids == nil) {
                        self.sessionBids = NSMutableArray()

                    } else {
                        lastSessionBid = self.sessionBids.objectAtIndex(self.sessionBids.count - 1) as! NSDictionary
                        previousHighBid = Int(lastSessionBid.objectForKey("bid") as! String)
                    }

                    if( previousHighBid >= Int(self.bidTextField.text!)) {
                        print("bid is lower than current bid")
                        SVProgressHUD.showErrorWithStatus("Bid is lower than current bid!")
                        return

                    } else {

                        self.sessionBids!.addObject(NSDictionary(objects: [PFUser.currentUser().objectId, PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("username"), self.bidTextField.text], forKeys: ["user", "name", "bid"]))
                        SVProgressHUD.showProgress(75)
                        self.session.setObject(self.sessionBids, forKey: "bids")
                        self.session.save()
                        self.keyboardShowing = false
                        self.reloadSessionBids()
                        SVProgressHUD.showProgress(100)
                        SVProgressHUD.showSuccessWithStatus("Successfully Added Bid")
                    }

                } else {
                    SVProgressHUD.showErrorWithStatus("Bid must be a number!")
                }
```

Comment: please show something about `PFUser`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `init(objects: [AnyObject], forKeys keys: [NSCopying])` initializer of NSDictionary. **objects: [AnyObject]**  can't contain Optionals (according to its declaration), and it seems that `PFUser.currentUser().objectId`, `PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("username")`, `self.bidTextField.text` are all Optionals, that's why you're getting the error.

To resolve this, as [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) suggested, you'll need to unwrap all the Optionals in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Both the objects and the keys of a dictionary must not be `nil`.
Make sure that all objects are non-optionals.

Comment: i have posted my full block of code if you're able to give some more detailed advice with it :)

Comment: At least unwrap `self.bidTextField.text!` in the initialization line and maybe also the other objects if they could be `nil`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling NSDictionary's
`public init(objects: UnsafePointer<AnyObject?>, forKeys keys: UnsafePointer<NSCopying?>, count cnt: Int)` instead:

```
self.sessionBids!.addObject(NSDictionary(objects: [PFUser.currentUser().objectId, PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("username"), self.bidTextField.text], forKeys: ["user", "name", "bid"], count: 3))
```

Alternatively, try using a native dictionary instead of an NSDictionary.

Say:

```
var bidDict = [String : AnyObject]()
bid["user"] = PFUser.currentUser().objectId ?? "unknown"
bid["name"] = PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("username") ?? "unknown"
bid["bid"] = self.bidTextField.text ?? "unknown"
```

Then insert into your array:

```
self.sessionBids!.addObject(bid)
```